# Emberjs router changes

Tags: ember.js, router

I found following post:

http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/12/22/this-week-in-ember-js-3/

Is this changes will reflect in future or already part of emberjs(`ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min`)?

If future, is there any roadmap?

Answer (score 2):

No, those changes are not part of `ember-1.0.0-pre.2`. However, you can grab the code [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js) and then run `bundle` and `rake dist` and you'll get the compiled ember.js files in the `dist` directory.

AFAIK, there's no roadmap but the [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues?milestone=1&page=1&state=open) (I've filtered for Milestone 1.0 Beta issues only) give a quite good impression of what is coming.